# Magento new notification emails not being sent to Store Owner

Tags: email, adminnotification, magento-1.9.2.1

When order is placed user/buyer gets an email notification that he made a purchase. That's fine.

But did Magento developers thought that the store owner should also be  notified about new order?

I believe I have done everything correctly with the cron.

I can see that table core_email_queue has 3 emails in it and they don't get cleared i.e they are not being sent.

I've setup emails correctly in Magento backend and even installed SMTP Pro extension but this doesn't help also. Emails to customer after order being placed are sent fine, contact form from store frontend works great also, the only thing I can't figure out is why the Store Owner doesn't receive the email about new order.

I have tried cron.php and setting up the cron job to execute this file and nothing has worked so far.

Comment: I know you said the cron is working fine, but everything you just said describes a cron issue. Are records in cron_schedule up to date? That's what will tell you if the cron is actually running as intended. If yes, are there any errors in the records?

Comment: Maybe try and open the cron.php in your browser to make sure it's not a cron issue

Comment: @Predrag - welcome to our corner of the internet. Congratulations on your very first post here. I have edited your question to remove the inflammatory portions. There is no need to patronize, we're all here to help.

Comment: @Milan, I've tried executing cron.php myself through the browser and from cl usinmg wget and curl and this also doesn't help.

Comment: @RyanH. I am sure that my cron is working because I have a dozen sh scripts which are executing all at the different time everyday. I looked up in mysql table cron_schedule and are couple of entries with success status and lots of them with Pending status. I don't know am I allowed to post external links to show you the screenshot of this table?

Comment: If the e-mails are sent to the customers, the bcc method metioned by @philwinkle should work. Did you check your Gmail spam folder? Gmail can be pretty picky.

Comment: @Milan Yes of course. I also have installed filter in gmail not to ever send to spam emails from this address which I use for store. I'm thinking about some free extension to solve this problem. Any recommendations?

Comment: Not sure about a custom extension, this should normally work out of the box. Did you set the e-mail address in the correct configuration scope (top left dropdown in config) ? The store specific configuration might override the default config.

Comment: @Milan The emails are set for Basic Configuration scope i.e Main Website > Default store > Default store view. If you set emails for basic configuration than this overrides main website, default store and default store view, and this is ok. No clue what's wrong, cron.php is executing every 5 min. But still no notification email when order is placed.

Comment: When you place an order using the same gmail address thats used as bcc as customer address, does the customer confirmation arrive?

Comment: @Milan Yes. Customer receives order confirmation either way, no matter which address I am using for a store owner or general contact address. The contact form also works fine. The only problem is that admin / store owner does not receive any email about order being made.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Magento.SE!

This is a handy feature to have, and you're in luck - you can do this in Magento!

Head on over to the admin panel under `System > Config > Sales Emails` and expand the `Order` section:

[image]

Here you can put any email address in the BCC field. This is where you would put any email recipient (including Store Owner) to be copied on new order emails.

As you could also already tell - there are many other email types that you can set this BCC setting for. Have a field day! Go nuts! BCC ALL THE THINGS!

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks philwinkle, but this doesn't help also. I've put my gmail address at bcc field and then placed another order which shows up btw in backend but no notification on admin email received nor the gmail address I've put previously in bcc.